# How to set fps in pygame in order to prevent lag?

Tags: python-2.7, pygame, frame-rate

How can I set a suitable fps number in pygame for any kind of monitor running my game? I know I can set fps using `pygame.time.Clock().tick(fps)` but how can I set suitable fps?

Please post example python code along with answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure that I understand the question being asked, but I think you will just have to experiment with different numbers and find out what works for you.  I find that around 50-100 is a good range.

If what you are trying to do is make game events only update a certain number of times per second while rendering happens as fast as the computer is able to handle it, this is a very complex process and probably not very easily done in pygame.

Answer (score 1):

The trick I've figured out is not limiting the frame rate, but calculating based on time. The pygame.time.Clock.tick() returns time in milliseconds, which you can then pass to other parts of the program to calculate events or animation updates.

For example, I currently use a pair of variable in my Player object to store the center point of the player's character multiplied by 1000 to be able to update it as an int from `tick()`. I think update it each loop, after solving which direction the player is moving, with the following code:

```
    self.x += self.speed * time * xmove
    self.y += self.speed * time * ymove
    self.rect.centerx = self.x / 1000
    self.rect.centery = self.y / 1000
```

Additionally, I use that same `time` variable as part of the Spawner class to determine when new enemies should be spawned to the map, and for the movement of the enemies and bullets in the game.

This method has the bonus of keeping game play more or less the same across multiple frame rates.